# Generalized Voronoi graph (any package?)

Tags: ros, graph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,

I need to obtain a generalized Voronoi graph (GVG) from a grid map (like described here: http://www.sfbtr8.uni-bremen.de/project/r3/HGVG/hierarchicalVGraphs.html#Ref_2).

I have implemented my own node, but there still some tricks to solve and is not very efficient (i have used opencv libraries (cv::distanceTransform) but to obtain GVG from GVD there are lots of tricks).

Anyone knows any package that process the generalized Voronoi graph from the map?

Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46810/generalized-voronoi-graph-(any-package?)/) by [Filipe Santos](https://answers.ros.org/users/907/filipe-santos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 346 on 2012-10-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is some code for dynamic updates of Voronoi & distance maps in [alufr-ros-pkg](http://code.google.com/p/alufr-ros-pkg/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fdynamic_voronoi%2Fdynamicvoronoi), with some more information here:
[http://www.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~lau/dynamicvoronoi/](http://www.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/%7Elau/dynamicvoronoi/)

Maybe there is also code for Voronoi graphs in there.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1